# DHL Tracking HTML Form?

Tags: html, forms, api, tracking

Does anyone know if I can create an HTML Form to search the DHL tracking website?
http://www.dhl.co.uk/en/express/tracking.html

I have tried using the following but get the error 'down for maintenance':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE]>
<![endif]-->
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://www.dhl.co.uk/content/gb/en/express/tracking.shtml?brand=DHL&AWB=1212121212" method="post">

<input type="submit" value="go" />

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Will I have to use the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following HTML tracking sample enables you to insert a single waybill number into a tracking field and submit the request via your existing web page. This link takes you to the DHL tracking screen, automatically populating the shipment information.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DHL - Track By Tracking Number</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="get" action="http://www.dhl-usa.com/content/us/en/express/tracking.shtml?">
< input type=hidden name=brand VALUE="DHL">
<input type="text" name="AWB" size="10"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Big shout out to @WeezHard for dropping that form. I figured his solution is directed at DHL USA, so if you want a global DHL tracking form you can use the follow code.

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="https://www.dhl.com/global-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id=" target="_blank">
<input type=hidden name=submit VALUE="1">
<input type="text" name="tracking-id" size="10" placeholder="Enter your DHL waybill number here..."><br>
<input type="submit" value="Track">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified @WeezHard codes to adapt Aramex courier tracking

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="https://www.aramex.com/track/results? 
ShipmentNumber=" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="ShipmentNumber" size="11" placeholder="Enter your AWB"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Track">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

feel free to use it!  ;)